# Take int of day, month, year and convert to DD/MM/YYYY

Tags: java, date

I am writing a method to take a DOB of 3 integers - day, month, year and return the formatted version DD/MM/YYYY.

I am currently using dateFormatter and simple date format. Although when I run this it defaults to 01/01/1970 and I cannot change the date.

Any suggestions?

**Update**

Guys thanks for the below posts, problem solved!

Comment: A DateFormat is used to format instances of java.util.Date. Not an integer. BTW, there is now way to find out the day, month and year parts of a number obtained by summing these 3 parts. Use a LocalDate: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#of-int-int-int-

Answer (score 1):

Why use formatter? just do this:

```
   public String DateOfBirth(int day, int month, int year) 
{
    String DOB = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;

    return DOB;
}
```

If it's for an assignment, the teacher probably wants you to not use formatter.

Also, as someone else mentioned: If you are trying to concatenate integers as a string you need some string in between. Otherwise you are summing the values of the integers.

Comment: This will give you one-digit day and month if less than 10, for example, 2/4/2017. I understood the question as asking for two digits, like 02/04/2017. If your assumption about avoiding standard classes is correct (which I hope not), you may use `String.format()`.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.of( 2017 , 1 , 23 )
         .format( DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu" ) )
```

> 23/01/2017

## java.time

The modern way uses the java.time classes.

Avoid the old legacy date-time classes such as `Date` and `Calendar` as they are poorly designed, confusing, troublesome, and flawed.

### `LocalDate`

`LocalDate` represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone. Note that unlike the legacy classes, here the months have sane numbering 1-12 for January-December.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2017 , 1 , 23 );
```

### `DateTimeFormatter`

Generate a String representing that value by using a formatter object.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu" );

String output = ld.format( f );
```